# sometimes persistence is still allowed to loads data as an eagerly?

Tags: jpa, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-3.0, ejb-3.1

I read this in the EJB/JPA Book:

"Even if you mark the property as LAZY for a @Basic type, the persistence provider is still allowed to load the property eagerly. This is due to the fact that this feature requires class-level instrumentation. It should also be noted that lazy loading is neither really useful nor a significant performance optimization. It is best practice to eagerly load basic properties."

**QUESTION 1)**
If I set property as an LAZY, why e persistence provider is still allowed to load the property eagerly? when this happens? and why? is this for primitives only?

**QUESTION 2)**

"The @Basic annotation is the simplest form of mapping for a persistent property. This is the default mapping type for properties which are primitives, primitive wrapper types"

If I use does not use primitive or wrapper (for instance I use my class object), will he persistence provider is still allowed to load the property eagerly?

**QUESTION 3)**
"You do not need to tell your persistence manager explicitly that you're mapping a basic property because it can usually figure out how to map it to JDBC using the property's type."

As I understand this happens when I use primitives or wrappers, don't I? And how does it figure out how to map? Is there any obvious rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> QUESTION 1)If I set property as an LAZY, why e persistence provider is
>   still allowed to load the property eagerly? when this happens? and
>   why? is this for primitives only?

Because of performance issues: the JPA provider has the right (according to the JPA spec) to decide that it is better to fetch the field eagerly. This is valid also for wrapper fields & Strings. It is not specified when this happens, which means that can happen when the JPA provider considers it needed.

> QUESTION 2)"The @Basic annotation is the simplest form of mapping for
>   a persistent property. This is the default mapping type for properties
>   which are primitives, primitive wrapper types"
>   If I use does not use primitive or wrapper (for instance I use my
>   class object), will he persistence provider is still allowed to load
>   the property eagerly?

Actually yes, also for relationships you have the same rule, although almost always the JPA provider will consider your hint. Of course: when you have a field of type `YouClass`, you are not allowed to annotate it with @Basic and must use @ManyToOne-like annotations. You will read further about them.

> QUESTION 3) "You do not need to tell your persistence manager
>   explicitly that you're mapping a basic property because it can usually
>   figure out how to map it to JDBC using the property's type."
>
> As I understand this happens when I use primitives or wrappers, don't
>   I? And how does it figure out how to map? Is there any obvious rule?

That happens will all types listed in the documentation of the [@Basic annotation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Basic.html), not only those that you enumerated. The rule is pretty simple: String types are mapped as VARCHAR/CHAR like columns, number-fields like NUMBER (or DECIMAL) and so further.

Comment: As I understand, I can never write property value -lazy or eagerly. Everytime, JPA will decide which way is better.  If this is true, why we have possibility to tell JPA how to process data (Is this possibility  usable at all of JPA will automatically do that)?

Comment: As I said, it is a hint, not a requirement. Some JPA implementations may consider that hint or not. In the case of lazy relationships to other entities, it is almost always considered, which means that almost always the relationships ARE fetched lazy.